# Check all child based on parent ID and a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data set containing parent and child ID which its corresponding Indicator

My Input date is

```
Parent_ID Parent_InHome_Ind  Child_ID Child_InHome_Ind
100          Y                 500        Y
100          Y                 501        N
201          Y                 701        N
201          Y                 702        N
301          Y                 801        N
```

I need to extract all the records based on below two condition

1. For the same parent, If all the Child_InHome_Ind of a child_Id is 'N' then the corressponding Parent_InHome_Ind should be N.
2. For the same parent, if any one of the Child_InHome_Ind have diff value within its siblings, ignore these record.

The output should be

```
Parent_ID Parent_InHome_Ind  Child_ID Child_InHome_Ind 
201          Y                 701        N
201          Y                 702        N
301          Y                 801        N
```

I tried group by and list aggr but unable to frame a Oracle SQL query. can anyone please help here.

Comment: Your second condition would always be true if your first is true, so you only need to check condition 1? Is that correct or I am missing something?

Comment: Unless I miss understand what you are saying then your sample output or rules are incorrect.....   Parent_ID 201 has two children both with a Child_InHome_ind as 'N' according to rule 1. the Parent_InHome_Ind should be switched to 'N' not 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by the following self-joined aggregated query :

```
select
    t1.Parent_ID,
    decode( 
        min(decode( t2.Child_InHome_Ind, 'N', 0, 1)), 
        0, 'N', t1.Parent_InHome_Ind
    ) Parent_InHome_Ind,
    t1.Child_ID,
    t1.Child_InHome_Ind
from
    table t1
    inner join table t2 on t2.Parent_ID = t1.Parent_ID
having
    count(distinct t2.Child_InHome_Ind) = 1
group by 
    t1.Parent_ID,
    t1.Parent_InHome_Ind
    t1.Child_ID,
    t1.Child_InHome_Ind
```

Notes :

- the self-`INNER JOIN` allows to retrieve all records sharing the same parent
- the `HAVING BY` clause filters only allows children that all have the same `Child_InHome_Ind` (only one distinct value should be present for all children of the same parent)
- in the `SELECT` clause, the `DECODE` statement handles the case when all children have their `Child_InHome_Ind` equal to `N`, and accordingly sets the column to `N` (else the original value is preserved)
  -

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your rules and not your sample data is correct the below should work.

GMB's answer looks like it would work but I think this is a simpler query that would also work

```
  with table_name as
   (select 100 as parent_id, 'Y' as Parent_InHome_Ind, 500 as Child_ID, 'Y' as Child_InHome_Ind from dual
    union 
    select 100, 'Y', 501, 'N' from dual
    union 
    select 201, 'Y', 701, 'N' from dual
    union 
    select 201, 'Y', 702, 'N' from dual
    union 
    select 301, 'Y', 801, 'N' from dual)
  select parent_id, decode(Child_InHome_Ind, 'N', 'N', 'Y') as Parent_InHome_Ind, child_id, Child_InHome_Ind from table_name tn
  where (select count(distinct child_INHome_ind) from Table_name tn1 where tn.parent_id = tn1.parent_id) = 1;
```

The where clause filters out any parent who has children with conflicting values then from there the parent_inHomeInd must match the child inHomeInd so the simplified decode should work.